# How to manually scale count of Seaborn Violinplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, visualization, violin-plot

I'm using Seaborn in Python to make split violinplots. The trouble is that one of my two hue's has a much smaller count that makes it almost imperceptible when side-by-side the other hue.

My question is how can I add a multiplier to scale the count on one side of the violin splits?

Here is the documentation of the kind of thing I'm doing:

[image]

And here is how it currently affecting me:

[image]

In the end I'd like it to be clearly perceptible that the right-side of the violins has a significantly smaller overall count -while still portraying its distribution.

Comment: you can change the `scale` parameter to `area` or even `width` but I'm afraid you can't have the effect of `count` and `area` at the same time

Comment: It would be better if you made your code written rather than a picture.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest that you solve this issue by displaying an enlarged view of the violin plot half that is hard to perceive. This can be done by using an [inset axes](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/zoom_inset_axes.html). Here is an example based on the one you have shared from the [seaborn docs](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.violinplot.html#seaborn.violinplot):

```
import seaborn as sns  # v 0.11.0

# Import sample dataset and generate seaborn violinplot
tips = sns.load_dataset('tips')
ax = sns.violinplot(x="day", y="total_bill", hue="sex", data=tips, palette="Set2",
                    split=True, scale="count", inner="stick", scale_hue=False, bw=.2)
ax.figure.set_size_inches(10,4)
ax.legend(loc='upper left', frameon=False)

# Create inset axes to zoom in on violinplot showing 'day'='Fri' & 'sex'='Female'
tips_fri_fem = tips[(tips['day']=='Fri') & (tips['sex']=='Female')]
axins = ax.inset_axes([0.44, 0.1, 0.06, 0.8])
sns.violinplot(data=tips_fri_fem, x='sex', y="total_bill", hue="sex",
               palette="Set2", split=True, scale="count", inner="stick",
               scale_hue=False, bw=.2, ax=axins)
axins.set_xlim(1, 1.5)
axins.set_ylim(0, 30)
axins.set_xlabel('')
axins.set_ylabel('')
axins.set_xticklabels('')
axins.legend().remove()

# Add rectangle without the connector lines to indicate area that is enlarged
rect, lines = ax.indicate_inset_zoom(axins, alpha=0.8)
rect.set_bounds(*rect.get_xy(), 0.1, 30)
for line in lines:
    line.remove()
```

[image: inset_axes]